# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ctc/wstx/stax/WstxInputFactory when using openCMIS

Tags: alfresco, classnotfoundexception, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am trying this new program that gets the document from Alfresco. 
Mine is Alfresco version 4.2 and latest openCMIS. Below is my code.

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Session session = null;
    OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContextImpl();
    operationContext.setCacheEnabled(true);


    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "admin");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "admin");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://alfresco-url.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom");

    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCALE_ISO3166_COUNTRY, "us");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCALE_ISO639_LANGUAGE, "en");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.LOCALE_VARIANT, "");


    Repository soleRepository = (Repository)sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0);
    session = soleRepository.createSession();

    session.setDefaultContext(operationContext);

    String cmisObjectId = "workspace://SpacesStore/u456ce2c-5675-3f66-fgh5-d45g567w35";

    CmisObject obj = session.getObject(new ObjectIdImpl(cmisObjectId));

}

}
```

I am getting the below exception at the last line.

> SLF4J: Failed to
>   load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to
>   no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ctc/wstx/stax/WstxInputFactory    at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AtomPubParser.parse(AtomPubParser.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.parse(AbstractAtomPubService.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:809)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:112)
>     at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:55) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     ... 8 more

Can anyone help me to find which JAR I need to add?

Comment: Just google for that package and class, adding "maven" might help narrowing this down

Answer (score 3):

You can find it here: [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory%22)

As suggested by Marged, it would be much easier using maven.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go fetch the jar from [here](http://www.findjar.com/class/com/ctc/wstx/stax/WstxInputFactory.html) and add it your classpath.